# store source of fileupload in mvc ef

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a Files table witch has a src (nvarchar). i want to add file. but when i create Controller and Views by VS, it makes a input type text. i want to have a input file, and store uploaded string in src field.
this is Create View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.src, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" />
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.src, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.src, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and this is Create Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,src")] Files files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Files.Add(files);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(files);
}
```

Model

```
public class Files
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string src { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show the model for `Files` (property `scr` needs to be typeof `HttpPostedFileBase`. But you cant store a file as a string, it needs to be `byte[]`

Comment: you mean i should change src type to byte in DB ?

Comment: If you want to store an uploaded file, then yes, but its recommend you store files in a file server, not in a database

Comment: i want to store file in server. i used Files table for their source. src is a string for file source in server. i just need to have a input file in the page rather input text. and when submiting form, it store file in server, get the source, and send source for src field

Comment: You mean you save the path in the database? You need a property (say) `HttpPostedFileBase Upload` in the model and use add `new { @type = "file" }` to the `EditorFor()` method (or just `<input name="Upload" type="file" />`) and in the POST method,save the file and add its path to the `scr` property before you save the `File` object to the database

Comment: you get my problem well, but i didnt your help well !
im new to mvc. so i dont know where i should use `HttpPostedFileBase Upload`. and cant work with POST method too.

Comment: Show you current model for `Files`. And where do you want to store the actual file?

Comment: its too long.. can i have your email and discuss it there ?

Comment: Just show a couple of properties including the `src` property.

Comment: `public int ID { get; set; }` and `public string src { get; set; }` is there. everything else is relations to other tables. actually i used ado.net EF generetor from database. it generated these models from database and in the database i have Files table with 2 fields: id and src. and i want to store actual file in a folder in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind a file input to a `string`. In the view, remove the `EditorFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` associated with property `scr` and replace with

```
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

and add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the form tag

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", yourControllerName, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Then change the POST method to

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  // Save the file to the server
  if (file.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName); // adjust path to suit
    file.SaveAs(path);
    // Save the path to the database
    Files model = new Files(){ scr = path };
    db.Files.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  // No file was selected so return the view with an error message
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please select a file");
  return View()
}
```

Comment: this code returns `NullReferenceException` for `if (file.ContentLentgh > 0)`

Comment: You have not added the `enctype` attribute to the form - see edit